# NCommon - changes in 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, ncommon

I updated my NCommon version to 1.1. It looks like there are breaking changes. What happened to:

1. the Store container class?
2. the NHRepository constructor that accepts an ISession?

How should I modify my code to address these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is probably more suited for the NCommon project [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/ncommon) or [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/ncommon/issues/list). Closer to the source, the better :)

Answer (score 0):

JAson, check this: http://www.codeinsanity.com/2010/04/refactoring-storage-in-ncommon-11.html

The is NCommon's author blog. I had the same question and the above mentioned blog explained me the details.